# Unable to get gradle working android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have left android studio for sometime now. I downloaded 'Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2' I cloned a project from github and for some reason I cannot get the project setup.

Usually gradle shows up on the right panel, but it is not.
[image]

What am I missing?

It is also not showing up here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the main menu go to `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`

Comment: I checked that it is not there

Comment: Check the plugins section, the Gradle plugin might be is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I forgot to pull the gradle scripts, after pulling it and syncing, everything started working as expected.